# How to output form data read from JSON feed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a form wizard based on JSON data feed using jquery.dform. ie it reads the JSON feed and populates the form fields.

Now, I want to be able to output or alert the form field values based on user changes or updates in the form, when the user clicks submit.

I am using jquery.dfrom to generate a form based on JSON example here 
https://github.com/daffl/jquery.dform

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Get started with jQuery dForm</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
    input, label {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
</style>
<body>
<!--<form id="demo-1-form"></form>
<pre data-for="demo-1"></pre>  -->

<form id="demo-2-form"></form>
<pre data-for="demo-2"></pre>

<!-- Load jQuery and the minified plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/jquery.dform-1.0.1.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript" class="demo" id="demo-2">
$('#demo-2-form').dform({
    "action":"index.html",
    "method":"post",
    "html":[
        {
            "type":"fieldset",
            "caption":"User information",
            "html":[
                {
                    "name":"email",
                    "caption":"Email address",
                    "type":"text",
                    "placeholder":"E.g. user@example.com",
                    "validate":{
                        "email":true
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name":"password",
                    "caption":"Password",
                    "type":"password",
                    "id":"registration-password",
                    "validate":{
                        "required":true,
                        "minlength":5,
                        "messages":{
                            "required":"Please enter a password",
                            "minlength":"At least {0} characters long"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name":"password-repeat",
                    "caption":"Repeat password",
                    "type":"password",
                    "validate":{
                        "equalTo":"#registration-password",
                        "messages":{
                            "equalTo":"Please repeat your password"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type":"radiobuttons",
                    "caption":"Sex",
                    "name":"sex",
                    "class":"labellist",
                    "options":{
                        "f":"Female",
                        "m":"Male"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type":"checkboxes",
                    "name":"test",
                    "caption":"Receive newsletter about",
                    "class":"labellist",
                    "options":{
                        "updates":"Product updates",
                        "errors":{
                            "value":"security",
                            "caption":"Security warnings",
                            "checked":"checked"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type":"fieldset",
            "caption":"Address information",
            "html":[
                {
                    "name":"name",
                    "caption":"Your name",
                    "type":"text",
                    "placeholder":"E.g. John Doe"
                },
                {
                    "name":"address",
                    "caption":"Address",
                    "type":"text",
                    "validate":{ "required":true }
                },
                {
                    "name":"zip",
                    "caption":"ZIP code",
                    "type":"text",
                    "size":5,
                    "validate":{ "required":true }
                },
                {
                    "name":"city",
                    "caption":"City",
                    "type":"text",
                    "validate":{ "required":true }
                },
                {
                    "type":"select",
                    "name":"continent",
                    "caption":"Choose a continent",
                    "options":{
                        "america":"America",
                        "europe":{
                            "selected":"true",
                            "id":"europe-option",
                            "value":"europe",
                            "html":"Europe"
                        },
                        "asia":"Asia",
                        "africa":"Africa",
                        "australia":"Australia"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type":"submit",
            "value":"Signup"
        }
    ]
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your attitude isn't appealing, the 'thanks' makes me think that you are lazy (no offense). Now, do you wish to compare the feed from one moment with the feed from another moment? And, you shouldn't ask 2 things (storage) in 1 question.

Comment: @EricG  I had no idea saying "Thanks or Thank you" to someone was a show of attitude. Last time I checked it was a sign of courteousness. I guess times are really changing.

Comment: My apologies, I don't mean to undervalue a good attitude/manners. I guess I extrapolated your attitude by (probably falsely I admit) assuming that you haven't tried it yourself; your post made me think as: 'I need something and I ask ppl for it - thank you'. If you know what I mean. But maybe it's me or my mood, apologies, truly. I appreciate your mature way of replying for sure :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jquery serialize() captures all the value/field in the forms and output it or any changes that user may have made to the form fields.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   $('#demo-2-form').on('submit', function(ev) {
        //alert($(this).serialize());
        var data = $(this).serialize(); // -> The URL encoded form data
         $("#results").text(data);

        ev.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```